# How to share connection between tasks in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

my pipeline looks like this

```
steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'ALZPipeline'
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: 'scripts/login.ps1'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
     azureSubscription: 'ALZPipeline'
     scriptType: 'pscore'
     scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
     scriptPath: '/deployment.ps1'
     arguments: '-action whatif'
```

What I want to achieve is to authenticate from the first task (login.ps1) where I do:

```
$azToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
Write-Output $azToken
$SecuredPasswordPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $azToken -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $SecuredPasswordPassword
```

And then use that authentication in my deployment.ps1 script, where I do:

```
parAssigneeObjectId = $(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($GroupName)'").Id
```

I am getting this error:

`Get-MgGroup : Authentication needed. Please call Connect-MgGraph.`

I am not sure if this is the right approach. My first task is using AzurePowerShell and second task AzureCLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using secrete variables between tasks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#set-secret-variable-in-a-script-with-logging-commands

as example:

login.ps1

```
$azToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
Write-Output $azToken
$SecuredPasswordPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $azToken -AsPlainText -Force
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mySecretVal;issecret=true]$SecuredPasswordPassword"
```

deployment.ps1

```
$SecuredPasswordPassword = $env:mySecretVal
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $SecuredPasswordPassword
parAssigneeObjectId = $(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($GroupName)'").Id
```